# What is the free environment to deploy an application built with docker compose

Tags: docker, java, web, cloud, docker-compose

Is there a free cloud service that allows to deploy a web application developed with **JSf** and **Mysql**.
The application is built locally with **docker compose** using both the docker images of Wildfly and Mysql and it works fine.

It remains to deploy it in the cloud to test the operation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there are several free cloud services that allow you to deploy web applications. Some popular options include:

1. Heroku - It provides a free tier with limited resources for hosting
   small applications.
2. Google Cloud Platform (GCP) - It offers a free tier with limited
   resources for new users to test the platform and deploy
   applications.
3. AWS Elastic Beanstalk - It provides a free tier with limited
   resources for deploying and running web applications and services.
4. Microsoft Azure - It offers a free tier with limited resources for
   new users to try the platform and deploy applications.